# selenium doesn't get all the information i want

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a program which automatically gets information from [this site](https://infographics.channelnewsasia.com/covid-19/map.html) and to begin with I've started small to only collect all the countries using the classes of the elements.  However, it seems to be very inconsistent and keeps giving results such as:

['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Liechtenstein', 'US Virgin Islands', 'Libya', 'Malawi', 'French Polynesia', 'Syria', 'Angola', 'Macau', 'Zimbabwe', 'Eritrea', 'Saint Martin', 'Mauritania', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Nicaragua', 'Botswana', 'Timor-Leste', 'Gambia', 'Grenada', 'Bhutan', 'Laos', 'Belize', 'Fiji', 'New Caledonia', 'Saint Lucia', 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Curacao', 'Dominica', 'Namibia', 'Burundi', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Falkland Islands', 'Turks and Caicos', 'Vatican City', 'Comoros', 'Greenland', 'Montserrat', 'Seychelles', 'Suriname', 'British Virgin Islands', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Saint Barthelemy', 'Anguilla', 'Lesotho']

and the previous time i ran the code it started at "Malawi" with all the blank texts as well. 
This is outputed from:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://infographics.channelnewsasia.com/covid-19/map.html")

info = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dataDivRow")
ct = []
for inf in info:
    countries = inf.find_elements_by_class_name("dataDivCol1")
    for cunt in countries:
        ct.append(cunt.text)

print(ct)
```

How would I go about getting all the country names from this site?

UPDATE: after running this programme a third time, it just gives me a completely empty list.  What would be the problem in my code? Thanks

UPDATE 2: I tried adding a sleep function for 30 seconds as my computer is considerably slow and I thought that was the problem. However, after running the code again I still receive a list filled with empty strings

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind then I got selenium to open up the list using .click() on the button to open up the list and it worked as to access the list you have to click on  the "TAB" button.  Then after it opened the list I would get the data.  Code works fine now.